# Filtering average calculation with where does not work

Tags: xquery

I am trying to use the `avg(...)` function with a `where` clause, but it is not working:

```
let $x := doc("boats.xml")/boats/boat/price
           where $x < 100000
           return avg($x)
```

I am trying to find the average of all boats that are less than 100k

```
let $x := doc("boats.xml")/boats/boat/price
           return avg($x)
```

The code works for all boats. Why doesn't the first one work for boats less than 100k?

This does not work either. It gives me a list of the prices under 100k instead:

```
 for $x in doc("boats.xml")/boats/boat
                    where $x/price<100000
                    return avg($x/price)
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. For a good question, generally make sure the problem you describe can be reproduced -- especially for XQuery questions, this pretty much _always_ includes the exact example input you work with. Cut it down to a reasonable length, but be sure to work with this exact input for the question. Then, "not working" _never_ forms a good problem description: "Calculates the average over all boat prizes" would be much better in this case. Finally, also include the wrong and expected output of your query (just calculate it by hand for the small example document you provided).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is easily revealed by returning `$x` instead of calculating the average: your first query declares `$x` as sequence of all prices (so `$x` is `(50000, 80000, 150000)` in my example document below). `$x < 100000` is thus `(50000, 80000, 150000) < 100000`, which evaluates in a set-based manner and validates to `true` if *any* element in the sequence is smaller than 100000; `avg($x)` finally takes the original list again and calculates the average on this.

Your third query is a good starting point towards the expected solution (and correctly filters), but fails as you calculate the average prize for each prize instead of the actual average over all prize values.

As you did not provide example input, I defined following:

```
let $boats := document {
  <boats>
    <boat>
      <price>50000</price>
    </boat>
    <boat>
      <price>80000</price>
    </boat>
    <boat>
      <price>150000</price>
    </boat>
  </boats>
}

return avg(
  for $boat in $boats/boats/boat
  where $boat/price < 100000
  return $boat/price
)
```

This query returns the expects 65000 for the provided input.

Answer (score 0):

For queries like this it's often simpler to use the XPath subset of XQuery, rather than using a FLWOR expression. It's just

```
avg(doc("boats.xml")/boats/boat/price[. < 100000])
```

Or I quite like the XPath 3.1 pipe syntax

```
doc("boats.xml")/boats/boat/price[. < 100000] => avg()
```